# AWS AppSync User relations for FriendsList

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

I have a problem with AWS AppSync and ApolloClient.
How can I use an association between users in the Amazon Service named AppSync, that is, a connection as node and edge. What I want to do is when I follow the users, I would like to see the flow of all users with a single request. 
It is the request that I want to be. How do I build a structure for this?

```
query {
    getFeeds(id:"myUserId") {
    following {
      userFeed {
        id
        ImageDataUrl
        textData
        date
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The schema I created is as follows**

```
type Comments {
    id: ID!
    date: Int!
    message: String!
    user: User
}
type Feed {
    id: ID!
    user: User!
    date: Int!
    textData: String
    ImageDataUrl: String
    VideoDataUrl: String
    likes: Like
    comments: [Comments]
}

#Objects
type Like {
    id: ID!
    number: Int!
    likers: [User]
}
}
type Query {
    getAllUsers(limit: Int): [User]
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    imageUrl: String!
    imageThumbUrl: String!
    followers: [User]
    following: [User]
    userFeed: [Feed]
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible in AppSync today.

To accomplish this, you could add a query field to your schema called `getUser` (`getUser` makes more sense than `getFeeds` in this case) and it would have a resolver which retrieves a User object from a data source.

```
type Query {
    getAllUsers(limit: Int): [User]
    getUser(id:ID!): User
}
```

Then, you can also add resolvers on the `User.following` and `User.userFeed` fields. The `User.following` resolver would query your data source and retrieve users whom somebody is following. The `User.userFeed` resolver would query your data source to retrieve a list of user feeds.

Both of these resolvers (`User.following` and `User.userFeed`) should utilize `$context.source` in the resolver's request mapping template. This variable will contain the result of your `getUser` resolver. The request mapping template's job is to create a query which your data source understands.

An example request mapping template which might be attached to `User.following` could be similar to the following. It would query a table named "Following", which has a primary partition key of id (the id of the user):

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "id = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : {
                ## Use the result of getUser to populate the query parameter **
                "S" : "${ctx.source.id}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to do something similar for `User.userFeed` resolver.

After you're all setup, you can run the below query, and the following will happen:

```
query {
    getUser(id:"myUserId") {
    following {
      userFeed {
        id
        ImageDataUrl
        textData
        date
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. `getUser` resolver will run first. It will query your User data source and retrieve the user.
2. `User.following` resolver will run. It will use the result of it's parent field resolver (`getUser`) to query the data source for following.
3. `User.userFeed` resolver will run. It will use the result of it's parent field resolver (`getUser`) to query the user feed data source.